# Echo German characters from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, character

I have a database full of German contacts.

The database itself displays all the unique German characters fine (when i'm looking at it in the admin control panel), but when I echo any special German character onto my site it displays as a � (or an empty square on Windows).

How can I get it to output the correct characters?

Everything is set to UTF-8 (the database table, columns and webpage encoding).

Comment: How about connection you used to connect to mysql via php?

Comment: What? I don't understand what you're asking...

Comment: *If you are not sure what I refer to, that's could be the reason* Which function/method you are using to connect mysql?

Comment: Using while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ to echo out all the rows in the database.

Comment: mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY COMPANY ASC, LASTNAME ASC"; $result=mysql_query($sql);

Comment: Simply you did not specify connect using UTF-8 ... you can add this after mysql_connect -- `mysql_query('set names utf8');`. However, is year 2011 ... don't use mysql function, mysqli or PDO is the industry standard

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix to change connection charset (and I believe that's your problem) is open the connection and then exec query 'set names utf8;'. If you are using php version greater than 5, then you can mysql_set_charset('utf8') instead of exec the query. That's the preferred way.

But please notice that that query needs to be executed every time you open the connection so it will raise count of your mysql queries.

```
<?php
$mysql = mysql_connect('localhost','user1','pass1');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
.... 
?>
```

Comment: Yes utf8 is the way to do it. For me to have greek working properly I have done these three things: 1.Mysql tables collation, characterset are set to utf, 2.when I connect to mysql I too use mysql_set_characterset, 3.In html header I use the proper encoding too. In addition if you use the registry or singleton aproach the connection is set only once so there is no extra cost for using mysql characterset.